# Which of these methods can be used to block network access for a browser extension in MS Edge?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, registry, microsoft-edge

I procrastinate a lot, so I added [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sitesentry-block-websites/pgoeobojimoocdnilcajmjihiabcmabn) extension to my MS Edge browser. My problem is this has a less reviews and less users and this asks permission to run in background even when the browser is closed. I turned off permission for running background processes in Edge settings but, I am still paranoid about its ability to access network. This extension works even without an internet connection. I cannot use a different extension, because this is the only extension that has the features I want. I don't have an advanced knowledge about technology, but up to my knowledge, I feel like following methods would work.

1. Find the web addresses this extension communicates with and block them in hosts file.
2. Use the registry editor to add a policy to block internet access to that extension.

I think the first method would work, but I am not smart enough to find these web addresses. I would appreciate if someone could give me instructions to find them, if you think this method would work.

If you think the first method is not effective, I feel like the second method would work, but I am not sure how to do it. I researched a lot about which policies I can use to force the extension to not use network but, I couldn't find such setting. I am sorry if there is no such policy which you can add by registry editor, I felt like I am not smart enough to find it. If there is such policy I would appreciate if someone could show me how to use it to block internet access for the extension.

Sorry if my English is bad and, if my methods stupid. I would appreciate if there is a working method, that is different to methods I mentioned above. If you know a method please be kind enough to post it. I really need an answer to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you turned off permission for running background processes in Edge settings, the extension won't access network after you closed Edge.

If you still want to block network access for that extension, the two ways you mention are not feasible. The only workaround I can figure out is below:

1. Open `edge://extensions/`.
2. Click "Details" under that extension.
3. In "Site access", choose "On specific sites" and add a nonexistent site URL.